# How Can I Reduce The Time Taken For The Code Execution Below?

Tags: c, performance

Purpose: To store numbers between 1-1000 in a random order.

My Code:

```
#include<time.h>

int main(){

    int arr[1000]={0}, store[1000];
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        int no;
        while(1){
            srand(time(0));
            no=rand();
            no%=1001;

            if(no==0)
                continue;

            //This ensures Loop will continue till the time a unique random number is generated
            if(arr[no-1]!=no){ 
                arr[no-1]=no; 
                break;
            }

        }

        store[i]=no;
    }
```

For me the code works perfectly fine,however, it took me 58 minutes to execute. Is there a way to speed up the program?

Practical Purpose: I have around 4000 employees and I want to give each one of them a unique random number for an upcoming project.

I tried to execute a code using 1000 to check the efficiency.

Comment: Somewhat related to your problem: You should only call `srand` *once*. If you call it inside a tight loop you will set the seed to the same value multiple times which will lead to the very same random number being generated multiple times.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's very much related. You could post that as an answer. :-) (or find a duplicate)

Comment: Wouldn't using GUIDs/UUIDs be a better idea?

Comment: Surely each employee has an employee number - would that do?

Comment: As for alternative ways of solving your problem, you could create a [*set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) with 1000 random numbers, then just iterate over that set and assign to the "users".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude They need to be unique.

Comment: Thank you so much @Someprogrammerdude it really helped.

Comment: By it i mean calling srand only once

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw That's what the set is for. While the number of elements in the set is less than 1000, generate a new random number and insert into the set. That will lead to it having 1000 *unique* random numbers.

Comment: Another possible solution, just create an array of 1000 elements, each initialized from `1` to `1000` *in order*. Then select a random *element* from that array and use for your purpose.

Comment: It seams a very contrived question. Why do they need to be random? You have limited them to the range 1 to n. I see no advantage in actually randomising them. The ID is not the index, but if you want to assign them an ID just make it the index, to start with. People will get deleted or added etc this will change. Thats fine. Adding new people is easy, just add then with the next ID so guaranteeing that ID has never been used.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you have missed the point again. How do you not randomly pick the same number twice?

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw Please read the link I provided about the set data structure. It's a data-type that contain unique keys. You can not insert duplicates. That's why one can generate random numbers without bothering checking for duplicates, as that will be handled by the insertion into the set.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array containing 1 to n. Iterate through the list and swap that entry with one that is randomly selected. You will then have a random list containing 1 to n.

Answer (score 0):

From your first sentence the numbers do not have to be random but only need to be in random order.

Therefore you can try a simple approach:

- Create an array arr of n elements and initialize with values 1..n
- run a loop (counter i) over range 0..n-1

  - Pick a random number x in range 0..n-i-1
  - Swap element at index i with index i+x

With this algorithm you don't need to worry about collisions of random numbers.
You swap the numbers and afterwards you decrease the range of candidates.
A number picked once is not available to pick in later steps.

This solution is similar to William's answer. I don't really know if the result has better "randomness" or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid branches on random numbers. And it will most likely run faster on modern processors.

This because the processor is not able to predict which way to chose on random numbers.

For example

```
while(1){
    srand(time(0));
    no=rand();
    no%=1001;
    if(no==0)
        continue;
    // ...
}
```

could be changed to

```
srand(time(0)); // better outside the loop
while(1) {
    no = rand() % 1000 + 1;
    // ...
}
```